# Values not being returned

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using a function to retrieve product information based on two parameters `$request` and `$id`. The request is processed and the correct database field is returned to be used in the query. The information however isn't being returned but the `$request` as a string is.

```
public function productInformation($request,$id) {

    switch($request) {

        case "id":
            $request = "id";
            break;
        case "desc":
            $request = "description";
            break;
        case "slug":
            $request = "slug";
            break;
        case "parent":
            $request = "parent";
            break;
        case "thumb":
            $request = "thumb_url";
            break;
        case "image":
            $request = "image_url";
            break;
        case "visible":
            $request = "visibility";
            break;
        case "time":
            $request = "stamp";
            break;  
    }

    $connect = new dbconnect;
    $connect->query("SELECT :request FROM products WHERE id = :id");
    $connect->bind(":request",$request);
    $connect->bind(":id",$id);
    $query = $connect->single();

    return $query[$request];

}
```

So if `$request = "desc"`, `return $query[$request]` will return `description` as a string? I'm calling the correct array key but I'm not too sure what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind column names (or table names), only data values.... i.e. you can't bind `$request` as it's a column name

```
$connect->query(sprint("SELECT %s FROM products WHERE id = :id", $request));
$connect->bind(":id",$id);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to put `:request` through function `bind()` because through your switch is not chance to SQL Injection. So you can put your `$request` variable only as string to query. And also you can not create params with tables.